# Unable to remove blank rows from JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, rowfilter

I have created a `JTable` which sometimes will have blank rows in. I wanted to remove these automatically. I know you can do it manually via `model.removeRow(0)` which would remove the first row but this table needs to be able to do it automatically. However when I run the following code below it does nothing. It is meant to look at the first cell in the row and if that is empty, in this case the rest of the row will be as well, it should remove the row. I would greatly appreciate any help in overcoming this problem

```
//CompData...
nextPosition=0
String[] aHeaders = {"Athlete ID","Forename","Surname","On The Team"};

    model = new DefaultTableModel(compTableData,aHeaders)
    {
        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) 
        {
            if (column < 3) 
            {
                return false;
            } 

            else 
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        public boolean removeRow(int row, int column)
        {
            for(int i=0;i<nextPosition;i++)
            {
                if(athTable.getModel().getValueAt(i,0).equals(""))
                {
                    return row == i;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    };

    athTable = new JTable(model);
```

Comment: When does removeRow get called? You could use a RowFilter and filter out rows that are blank. See [How to use tables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) and [RowFilter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/RowFilter.html) for more details

Comment: Does it not get called in the code `athTable = new JTable(model);` since it's in model @MadProgrammer

Comment: Okay nothing does. So where and how would I call it to make it work?

Comment: Tried `model.removeRow();` above `athTable = new JTable(model);` but that didn't work

Comment: Use a `RowFilter`, that's what it's designed to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You make use of a `RowFilter` to filter in/out rows based on your criteria, independent of the model

[image: Filter]

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.RowFilter;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableRowSorter;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(new String[]{"Fruit"}, 0);
                model.addRow(new String[]{"Banana"});
                model.addRow(new String[]{""});
                model.addRow(new String[]{"Apple"});
                model.addRow(new String[]{""});
                model.addRow(new String[]{"Strewberry"});
                model.addRow(new String[]{""});
                model.addRow(new String[]{"Grape"});
                model.addRow(new String[]{""});

                JTable table = new JTable(model);
                table.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
                TableRowSorter sorter = (TableRowSorter) table.getRowSorter();
                sorter.setRowFilter(new RowFilter<TableModel, Integer>() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean include(RowFilter.Entry<? extends TableModel, ? extends Integer> entry) {
                        boolean included = true;
                        Object cellValue = entry.getModel().getValueAt(entry.getIdentifier(), 0);
                        if (cellValue == null || cellValue.toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
                            included = false;
                        }
                        return included;
                    }
                });


                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new JScrollPane(table));
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

See 
[How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) and [How to use tables, Sorting and Filtering](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting) for more details